# JavaScript fullscreen API not working...?

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

So I'm making a game, and after much consideration I've decided I want to make it fullscreen.  I am using Chrome and have tried `$("container").webkitRequestFullScreen();`, but it's not working, even when I copy the files to my localhost server.


Is there something I'm missing?  Is my code wrong?  Here it is:

```
var cont = $("container");

if (cont.requestFullscreen) {
    cont.requestFullscreen();
}
if (cont.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    cont.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
if (cont.mozRequestFullscreen) {
    cont.mozRequestFullscreen();
}
if (cont.msRequestFullscreen) {
    cont.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```

So that's my code.  `cont` is a reference to my container div.

Thanks in advance!


EDIT: I keep forgetting to mention this - my `$` function is not jQuery, it's just returning `document.getElementById(id);`.


EDIT 2: And despite what StackOverflow says, I am not using IE!  I am not even looking for IE support!

Comment: A jQuery object doesn't have any kind of `requestFullscreen` method. DOM objects do. Try `cont.get(0).requestFullScreen()`.

Comment: This article shows how to use requestFullScreen and how to handle errors for various browsers - hope it helps! http://sorcery.smugmug.com/2012/06/06/using-html5s-fullscreen-api-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using jQuery.  I'll specify that in my OP.  I'm using a simple `document.getElementById` function.

Comment: But then  the `$("container")` is wrong, no?

Comment: Just making the code shorter - I don't want to type `$("container")` every time.

Comment: Ah, OK. Anything in the error console?

Comment: When I run `$("container").requestFullscreen();` or the Mozilla or IE prefixes, it returns an error that it is undefined, however, when I run the webkit prefixes, it just returns undefined.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, hmmm, I'll take a look and report back.

Comment: Okay, I did some fiddling and now it's going to fullscreen, but my canvas' background is completely white and I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using the suggestion that @Derek linked to, I was able to fix the problem.  However, now I have a blank wierd white canvas on the fullscreen, but that's another problem, so thanks for everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Vote for the IE 11 fullscreen bug (limited to iframes) here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814527/ie11-iframes-body-offsetwidth-incorrect-when-iframe-is-in-full-screen-mode#tabs